# Aspnetboilerplate AbpSession.GetTenantId() vs AbpSession.TenantId

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I am using https://aspnetboilerplate.com/for my project, I know that `AbpSession.GetTenantId()` should return current `TenantId`.

I also found that there are property `AbpSession.TenantId`

Can someone explain what is difference between `AbpSession.GetTenantId` and `AbpSession.TenantId`?

Answer (score 3):

`AbpSession.GetTenantId()` Gets current Tenant's Id. Throws `Abp.AbpException` if `Abp.Runtime.Session.IAbpSession.TenantId` is `null`.

`AbpSession.TenantId` Gets current `TenantId` or `null`. This `TenantId` should be the `TenantId` of the `Abp.Runtime.Session.IAbpSession.UserId`. It can be `null` if given `Abp.Runtime.Session.IAbpSession.UserId` is a host user or no user logged in.